# React-native flatlist to keep scrolling while touching view

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a drag and drop solution in react-native and I want to make my flatlist scroll if I drag an item in the upper 10 percent and bottom 10 percent of the view. So far the only way i can get it to happen is by calling a function that recursively dispatches a `this._flatList.scrollToOffset({ offset, animated: false });`. The recursive call stops when a certain condition is met but the scrolling effect is choppy. Any advice on making that smoother?

```js
// on move pan responder
onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { [props.horizontal ? 'moveX' : 'moveY']: this._moveAnim }], {
        listener: (evt, gestureState) => {
          const { moveX, moveY } = gestureState
          const { horizontal } = this.props
          this._move = horizontal ? moveX : moveY;
          const { pageY } = evt.nativeEvent;
          const tappedPixel = pageY;
          const topIndex = Math.floor(((tappedPixel - this._distanceFromTop + this._scrollOffset) - this._containerOffset) / 85);
          const bottomIndex = Math.floor(((tappedPixel + (85 - this._distanceFromTop) + this._scrollOffset) - this._containerOffset) / 85);
          this.setTopAndBottom(topIndex, bottomIndex);
          this.scrolling = true;
          this.scrollRec();
        }
      }),
      
// recursive scroll function 
scrollRec = () => {
    const { activeRow } = this.state;
    const { scrollPercent, data, } = this.props;
    const scrollRatio = scrollPercent / 100;
    const isLastItem = activeRow === data.length - 1;
    const fingerPosition = Math.max(0, this._move - this._containerOffset);

    const shouldScrollUp = fingerPosition < (this._containerSize * scrollRatio); // finger is in first 10 percent
    const shouldScrollDown = !isLastItem && fingerPosition > (this._containerSize * (1 - scrollRatio)) // finger is in last 10

    const nextSpacerIndex = this.getSpacerIndex(this._move, activeRow);

    if (nextSpacerIndex >= this.props.data.length) { this.scrolling = false; return this._flatList.scrollToEnd(); }
    if (nextSpacerIndex === -1) { this.scrolling = false; return; }
    if (shouldScrollUp) this.scroll(-20);
    else if (shouldScrollDown) this.scroll(20);
    else { this.scrolling = false; return; };

    setTimeout(this.scrollRec, 50);
  }
  
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, pass an `options` object to your `Animated.event` with your listener with `useNativeDriver` set to true

```
Animated.event([
  null,
  { [props.horizontal ? "moveX" : "moveY"]: this._moveAnim },
  { 
    listener: ...,
    useNativeDriver: true
  }
]);
```

Should make things significantly smoother.

edit: I feel I should add that there is probably a saner way to accomplish this, are you only using a FlatList because of it's "infinite" dimensions?